Google Scholar new paper alerts go to Gmail "trash" automatically (not spam)

I set alarm for a few scholars that I am interested in their research so that I get e-mail alert when they publish new papers. But they 'always' go to Gmail trash bin. (Not 'spam', but 'trash') It is very weird.
I thoght I have to ask this on StackExchange WebApps or somewhere else...
But 'Google Alerts' seems to work well -- https://www.google.com/alerts
Only 'Google Scholar Alerts' -- https://scholar.google.com/scholar_alerts?view_op=list_alerts has such a problem, so I publish the problem here.

Have you any fikters/rules setup on Gmail? Do you access Gmail from any other devices via IMAP or services like Outlook?
